# Jersey client upload size

Tags: java, rest, jersey

In a REST client, i upload several files to a server. 
In order to report to the user about the upload process, i use a progress bar.
The total size is set to the sum of the files dimension. 
This is an estimated value, because there are more bytes in the upload than the number of bytes in the file. 
**The question is: can I obtain the actual number of bytes of the upload *before* that the upload begins?** 
This would allow for the total size to be determined rather than estimated before the upload begins.

```
 FormDataMultiPart multiPart = new FormDataMultiPart();
 FileDataBodyPart fdbp = new FileDataBodyPart("data.zip", new File("data.zip")); 
 BodyPart bp = multiPart.bodyPart(fdbp);
 builder.post(String.class, multiPart);
```

Comment: What overhead do you think there is? Why? Wouldn't it be enough to get the exact sice of the file?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer - no.

More comprehensive one: you could. But it is not worth it. Basically you would need to somehow invoke MessageBodyWriter for FormDataMultiPart instance (see `org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.MultiPartWriter.writeTo(...)`) and get written bytes from that call. There are some issues related to this approach;

1. you'll do the writeTo operation twice - that means one request will consume twice resources as it should or
2. you'll have to cache the output and send it as an `byte[]` - you will need lots of memory (depends on data.zip file size).